# How to enable toolStrip1 from child form

Tags: c#

I am trying to enable/visible to true when I close childform. here is my sample code.  I would appreciate for your help.

```
//This code works perfectly 
private void TSBRekrytering_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FrmRekrytering RekryteringForm = new FrmRekrytering();
            RekryteringForm.MdiParent = this;
            RekryteringForm.Show();

            //Hide toolstrip for the FrmMain or MDI Parent Form
            TSFrmMain.Visible = false;
        }
```

But when I close `FrmRekrytering` I want to enable back the toolstrip for main form which is the MDI form.

Once again thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in Parent form

```
 private void TSBRekrytering_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FrmRekrytering RekryteringForm = new FrmRekrytering();
        RekryteringForm.Show(this);
        TSFrmMain.Visible = false;
    }

    public string toolstripvalue
    {
        get
        {
            return toolstripvalue;
        }
        set
        {
            toolStrip.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(value);
        }
    }
```

& this code in child form i.e. FrmRekrytering

```
  protected override void OnFormClosing(FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        ((MDIParent1)this.Owner).toolstripvalue = "true";
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help but I am still getting little bit or error do you know what causes this problem of: An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in

Comment: you have to hold value of toolstrip when passing data from parent to child form.
In your case perhaps it sends null value.

Comment: If you don't mind how should I have hold value of toolstrip? I am really new to C# and would really appreciate if you could guide how to do it. Thank you.